# Discrete subgroup of complex orthogonal group

Tags: lie-groups

Is there any reference for the discrete subgroup of complex orthogonal group SO(n,C)? Any classification or examples?

Comment: Do you want discrete subgroups with finite covolume or only discrete subgroups? In any case, there are many examples; if you want only discrete subgroups, a Schottky construction (ping-pong) gives you plenty. If you ask for lattices, many discrete groups can be constructed as unit groups of quadratic forms over an imaginary quadratic extension; a full classification is possible, if $n\geq 5$.

Comment: What is the reference for some detailed discussion either lattice or only discrete subgroup?  And what if n=4?

Comment: If $n\geq 5$, then all lattices are "arithmetic" and classification arises from Galois cohomology , Hasse principle, etc.You have to see the books of Margulis and of Platonov-Rapinchuk for details. If $n\leq 4$, then there are many more lattices.